# Can Any one knows how to use yoube upload widget without user login with google account

Tags: youtube

Please help me how to implement youtube upload widget without user login with google account

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless I completely missed the question, I don't think it's possible.

You can't upload to youtube without a google(youtube) acount to put the video on.